# Get rid of a few file-related tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The following tags should all be renamed to [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io):

- [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing) (100+ Questions)
- [file-writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-writing) (100-)
- [file-read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-read) (100+)
- [writefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writefile) (100-)
- [delete-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete-file) (100-)
- [file-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-manipulation) (100-)

Also, what about these:

- [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save) (4700+ Questions)
- [readfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readfile) (700+)
- [file-rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-rename) (500-)
- [file-exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-exists) (300-) - funny one, no Followers
- [multiple-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-files) (200+) - another funny one, also without Followers
- [createfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/createfile) (200+)
- [read-write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/read-write) (200-)
- [file-copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) (200-)
- [file-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-processing) (100+)
- [file-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-storage) (100-)
- [copyfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copyfile) (100-)

Comment: +1, but soft disagree on `readfile` -- it's a function name in a variety of languages.

Comment: Doesn't that make it a bit useless if it's available in multiple langs? Would it not be better to prefix such with *lang*... [tag:python-readfile]?

Comment: Sometimes.  There are a few tags that history has shown can live multiple lives just fine, such as `datetime`, which is a class in a variety of languages including PHP and C#.  It's not really an ideal situation (they're dictionary definition meta tags), but it *can* work sometimes, especially when there's overlap in what the functionality does.

Comment: [tag:datetime] is special in that it can mean a concept. [tag:readfile] however is more a name of some API than a concept of *reading files*.

Comment: The readfile tag has no wiki entry to guide anyone on when it should be used.  The first page of questions tagged 'readfile' does not make a convincing case for 'the `readfile` function'.

Comment: Like `readfile`, `writefile` is also the name of a specific Win32 function.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents:

It might be useful to be able to locate a question specific to deleting / reading / writing / opening / saving to a file / handling multiple files / creating folders. File I/O seems to broad for all of that, especially considering the already-existing 10 000+ questions with that tag.

Possibly a somewhat controversial view - perhaps we should burninate [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io) (reason - too broad), and replace it with the more specific tags listed here (but it's just something to think about - I'm not suggesting it ... yet). Anyway, back to the point...

Synonymize with [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io):

- [file-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-processing)
- [file-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-storage)
- [file-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-handling)

Remove / retag on a question-to-question basis, as these might not only related to file I/O, and don't have a particularly well-defined meaning:

- [read-write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/read-write)
- [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing)
- [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save)

No idea - just leave it, I guess:

- [filetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filetime)

Possibly worth keeping (or at least some derivation of these):
(same line should be considered being synonymized / retagged to one of them)

- [file-writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-writing) + [writefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writefile)
- [file-read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-read) + [reading-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reading-files) + [readfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readfile)
- [delete-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete-file)
- [open-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-file)
- [file-exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-exists)
- [multiple-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-files)
- [file-copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) + [copy-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copy-files)
- [createfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/createfile)

Additionally, I think it's worth trying to get some consistency going here with regard to the above tags, e.g. make all / most of the tags either `[file-...]` or `[...-file]`, and use consistent tenses, i.e. `read`, `write` and `copy`, not `read` and `writing` and `copying`.

I don't think [createfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/createfolder) really belongs with the rest - there are a lot of directory tags, and I don't think they should all be put under [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io), although [perhaps we should synonymize a few](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252105/synonymize-various-folder-tags).

Comment: I removed [tag:createfolder] from the list.

Answer (score 1):

[filetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filetime) is a specific Win32 structure. I would say it should be allowed to exist - most of the questions are using it correctly.

A few questions, like [How do I reliably retrieve a file's last modified time on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963397/how-do-i-reliably-retrieve-a-files-last-modified-time-on-os-x) and [PHP file modified time use GMT offset setting to report correct time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290847/php-file-modified-time-use-gmt-offset-setting-to-report-correct-time) are not using it in that sense. The tag should be removed from those questions, and possibly replaced with something more appropriate if applicable.

Comment: I would rather that tag be [tag:win32-filetime], to avoid any ambiguity.