# Organize my [directory], my [subdirectory], my [working-directory], or just organize my entire [directory-structure]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I was just looking through the folder tags, and I saw there's quite a few that need to be synonymized:

(Same line indicates suggested synonymization, first tag in line is suggested master tag)

- [directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directory) (x4617) + [dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dir) (x294) + [directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directories) (x418) + [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folder) (x2461) + [folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folders) (x683)
- [subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectory) (x365) + [subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectories) (x178) + [subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subfolder) (x389)
- [working-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/working-directory) (x140) + [current-working-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/current-working-directory) (x27) + [current-dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/current-dir) (x25) + [working-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/working-folder) (x4)
- [directory-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directory-structure) (x600) + [folder-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folder-structure) (x74)
- [shared-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-directory) (x9) + [shared-folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-folders) (x144)
- [create-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-directory) (x46) + [createfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/createfolder) (x22)
  Should probably also make sure [mkdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mkdir) (x453) only relates to the specific function, and retag generic create directory questions to the above.

Feel free to point out if I missed one.

Links to pages to suggest + vote on synonyms:
(need 2500 reputation and 5+ total answer score on the applicable tag)

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/directory/synonyms
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/subdirectory/synonyms
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/working-directory/synonyms
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/directory-structure/synonyms
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/create-directory/synonyms
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shared-directory/synonyms

Comment: Now we 'only' have to decide between folder or directory ;-) I vote for folder because it's shorter and has a smaller chance of misspelling.

Comment: I'd vote directory. It's the more canonical industry term, which is backed up by those tag counts. Tag autocomplete makes misspellings a nonissue.

Comment: @JanDoggen If they're synonyms, both would still work (the synonym would just automatically get replaced by the master tag), so the length and chance of misspelling is not really an issue.

Comment: What's the status on this? I recently saw a new question tagged with [tag:createfolder] and my first thought was to create a request for burnination, but it looks like it was kinda discussed here.

Comment: this still has not changed, having all those tags be non-synonym is ridiculous! Especially since most of these groupings barely have a following of 100 people

Comment: @LarsKristensen Burning them all is probably not a bad idea. I'm not really convinced any more that any of these tags are useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 years later.

I went ahead and added these as synonyms as they are all related to the same topic. I added them in the following direction:

directory x   9750  ←  folders x  0
directory x   9750  ←  folder x   5968

subdirectory x   756  ←  subfolder x   872
subdirectory x   756  ←  subdirectories x   380

working-directory x   264  ←  working-folder x   7
working-directory x   264  ←  current-dir x   37
working-directory x   264  ←  current-working-directory x   60

directory-structure x   1052  ←  folder-structure x   192

shared-folders x   272  ←  shared-directory x   21

create-directory x   92  ←  createfolder x   58

Some notes:

- [directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directory) and [directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directories) were already synonymized, so were [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folder) and [folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folders). So I synonymized both [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folder) and [folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folders) to [directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directory).
- Apart from [shared-folders], all other cases had the "directory" usage way more than the "folder" usage, and therefore I used the "directory" ones as the main tag.
- I will wait a couple of days before merging the tags, just to give some time to make changes, in case there is some issue.
- Most of these didn't have tag wikis, so I didn't save the tag wiki of any. Also, once merged, the wikis will be available to moderators, so we have not lost any wikis.
- Please let me know if there is any issue regarding the direction, I can always reverse it now.