# Rules for getting a tag synonym added seem too strict

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonym-process

The current rules seem very restrictive:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or
>   more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer
>   score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag,
>   can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved
>   when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they
>   reach a score of -2.

This can be a killer for tags with not too many users.

Particular case in point: I am looking at the [thoughtworks-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thoughtworks-go) tag. The product is from my employer (and I don't have more connection to it than that) and has just been open sourced and rebranded as `gocd` to avoid confusions with `golang` (as much as possible)

Currently, it is very tough to get people who have enough answer score in this tag to vote on a synonym suggestion. It seems to be much easier to just create a new tag, which shouldn't be the right solution.

Any pointers?

Comment: related: [Improving tag synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244) and [Count related tags fractionally when determining eligibility for voting on synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210617)

Comment: In this particular case, the system is doing its job well. The original tag has only 9 questions, and the new tag only 1. It **should** be very hard for users to create synonyms for barely-used tags, simply because the system does not need to be flooded with a bunch of synonyms for technologies that aren't even asked about very often here. Considering it's only 9 questions, retagging to the new tag [tag:go-cd] is a *far* better solution than creating a synonym at all.

Comment: @animuson - The tag has been in use for a long time. The first question was posted in April 09. Now, `gocd` has been added almost as a synonym to avoid confusions with golang. It made perfect sense for me to add this as a synonym. Anyways, till the community grows, will have to live with this.

Comment: This seems very out-of-place.  To _suggest_ a tag synonym you need 2500 rep and +5 in that tag?  That should read (if this were consistent with editing and suggesting tags) to _approve_ a tag synonym.  If a lower rep user in particular can suggest tags, why not tag synonyms?  We have a queue for everything else.

Comment: @animuson There are plenty of examples with tags with more questions, like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252105/synonymize-various-directory-tags). There may be enough users to create or vote on it, but they need to know about it and care first.