# merge tags working-directory and current-working-directory

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I found that the tags [working-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/working-directory) and [current-working-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/current-working-directory) seem to reflect the same concept. None of these has currently a tag guidance or wiki entry. One of it has more questions, one is closer to the commonly used CWD term. So I'm not sure which should be made a synonym.

Comment: This is part of [Synonymize various directory tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252105/2932052)