# Make [file-handling] and [file-io] synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io) (13,000+) and [file-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-handling) (500+ Questions) both involve operating on files:

- open
- close
- read
- write
- create
- delete

They got to point to the same tag, but I don't know which should be the master.

Comment: Is that a recurrence of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250969/get-rid-of-a-few-file-related-tags?

Comment: I thought it was better to make them synonyms instead of re-tagging.

Answer (score 2):

One could see a subtle difference in the meaning. "Handling" is the more general term, and may refer to *files* as "entities": Files are "objects" that can be moved around and organized in directories.

In contrast to that, "IO" rather refers to reading/writing the *contents* of files.

This may, however, be partially subjective, and even *if* there was a consensus, this is not make perfectly clear in the current wiki texts:

[file-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-handling)

> file-handling is an abstraction of common actions such as creating, opening, closing, reading, updating, writing, comparing and deleting files

[file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io)

> File I/O is input/output that involves the file system. This could include performing operations on directories and files, such as creation and deletion, reading files, and writing output to files.

Comment: Does this mean [tag:file-io] is a subset of [tag:file-handling]?

Comment: What about [tag:file]? The way you describe things, it looks like it should be a synonym with [tag:file-handling].

Comment: It's not necessarily a true subset. I just wanted to point out that one could see a difference between moving/renaming/organizing files, and actually *reading* and *writing* the contents of files. But the borders are blurred, and people may have different interpretations here.